# Activityのライフサイクルとスレッド

Tags: android

ActivityのライフサイクルとUIスレッドの処理について質問です。onCreateメソッドでHandlerを生成し、ログを表示する処理をpostしたところ、実行した際に、onResumeの後にログが表示されました。これは、ログを表示する処理がUIスレッドのMessage queueに追加されるより前に、Message queueにonRsumeの処理があるということでしょうか？Handlerでpostした処理が実行されるタイミングがいまいちわかりません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。onCreateからonResumeまでがひとつのキューイングされた処理であるというのは勉強になりました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

はい、その認識で正しいです。

`Handler` は生成したスレッド （ここでは UI スレッド） の `Looper` に処理をキューイングします。

`onCreate()` で追加した Message より先に `onResume()` が呼ばれるのがなぜかというと、

- Activity の起動処理もまた、UI スレッドにキューイングされている処理であること
- `onCreate()` のコールスタックを辿り、`ActivityThread#handleLaunchActivity()`メソッドの処理を読むこと

で分かります。説明に必要最低限な処理を抜き出すと以下になります。

```
// ここで onCreate() が呼び出されます
Activity a = performLaunchActivity(r, customIntent);
if (a != null) {
    r.createdConfig = new Configuration(mConfiguration);
    Bundle oldState = r.state;
    // ここで onResume() が呼び出されます
    handleResumeActivity(r.token, false, r.isForward, !r.activity.mFinished && !r.startsNotResumed);
    // 以下略
}
```

`onCreate()` の呼び出しと、`onResume()` の呼び出しはひとつのキューイングされた処理の中で行なわれているのです。

これらの処理が終わって初めて次のメッセージが取り出されるので、`Handler#post()` した内容は、`onResume()` の後で実行されます。